# Sinch Incoming Message TimeZone

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api

Documentation for [Incoming Message Timestamp](https://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/com/sinch/android/rtc/messaging/Message.html#getTimestamp()/%22Incoming%20Message%20Timestamp%22) states that incoming message is stamped with server time.

Unfortunately there is no TimeZone information tagged with the returned value and its difficult to do any sort of operation using the time. Like for example Sinch API replays back all the messages since last 30 days if the App was uninstalled and installed. Because of this reason the incoming message time stamp is very critical as we need to ignore an already replayed message.

Is there a way we can retrieve the TimeZone information of the server so that we can use time zone offset in all our time arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will update the documetation, its UTC time everywhere from us